# Insert ignore without the primary key

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a "user" table that contains id (PK, auto_increment), name, email (unique), cpf (unique), among other fields less important now. To add a user, I have data of all these tables mentioned but, obviously, id. CPF is a kind of Brazilian identity document.

I need to add a user if it doesn't exist on my table, and I can't overwrite. I googled, and discovered about the INSERT IGNORE. But how could this know that a user exists or not if I don't have the id, and this is my only primary key? How could I "teach" to the INSERT that these unique fields also can be compared?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a `unique` index on the cpf column.
Then, your insert ignore query will check for duplicate cpf identifier on every insertion.
And for more information on what would be a better approach to deal with duplicate insertions , see this : ["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Comment: CPF has already a unique index. So, the INSERT IGNORE will work as it is?